# subprocess with variable for lftp

Tags: python, subprocess, lftp

I'm trying to call subprocess from a python script. Script would call 'lftp' on linux with specific parameters as shown below. The problem as that I can not pass filename (filename will be different every day).

I was trying almost every combination but without success (for example: `${fname}`, `$fname`, `{fname}` and so on). I'm running out of ideas so I'm asking for a help.

Every time I get response from ftps server `Access failed: 550 The system cannot find the file specified`. I can properly log on and change folder.

```
import subprocess
import datetime


fname=different_every_day

proc=subprocess.call(
    ["lftp", "-u", "user:password", "ftps://servername:990", "-e",
     "set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; set ftp:ssl-force true; "
     "set ssl:verify-certificate no;get ${fname}"])

print(proc)
```

P.S. Close to proper answer was wagnifico, so i will accept his answer but for others who need solution it suppose to be as below:

```
proc=subprocess.call(["lftp","-u","user:pass","ftps://example.something","-e","set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; set ftp:ssl-force true; set ssl:verify-certificate no;cd Ewidencja;pget "+'"'+fname+'"'])
```

Comment: could you send me the eentire comand that you need to run on command line please?

Comment: Actually this is almost entire command but i will edit code in question. All i'm trying to do is that filename on ftps server will be different every day - it is generated automatically, for example today's filename will be:  2020-10-29 - All computers.xls , tomorrow there will be 2020-10-30 - All computers.xls and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing python and environment variables.

When you use `${fname}`, bash considers `fname` an environment variable, something known by your OS. Since it is not defined, it will use an empty value, thus, not finding the file.

You either need to define `fname` in your terminal and them call it in python, as in the question:

```
export fname='2020-10-29 - All computers.xls'
python your_code.py
```

Also, you need to add the flag `shell=True` when you call subprocess.call

Or define it entirely in python:

```
fname='2020-10-29 - All computers.xls'
proc=subprocess.call(
    ["lftp", "-u", "user:password", "ftps://servername:990", "-e",
     "set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; set ftp:ssl-force true; "
     "set ssl:verify-certificate no;get " + fname])
```

Comment: The first command won't work unless you also `export fname`. A better solution is `fname='whatever' python your_code.py` in a single command, which sets `fname` just for the duration of the Python process.  Or maybe refactor `your_code.py` to accept a filename as a command-line argument, which you can then pick up from `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: You are correct, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

here try it:

```
import os
import time
def python_to_bash(cli_args):
    output = os.popen(cli_args).read()    
    return output

file_name = str(time.time())+".xls"
python_to_bash("lftp -u user:password ftps://servername:990 -e set ftp:ssl-protect-data true set ftp:ssl-force true set ssl:verify-certificate no get "+file_name)
```

i dont know if the command that you need is right but when i need to make any dynamic names i use in this form

Comment: I think that problem is after '-e' because there suppose to be  '"' at the beginning and at the end , for example it should looks like: (...) -e "extra commands; get filename"

Comment: use simple commas ' at the start of python to bash and the end

Comment: here: `python_to_bash('command here'+filename+' "other options '+dinamic_options+'"')`

Comment: Somebody closed my post but i allready have solution for others: proc=subprocess.call(["lftp","-u","user:pass","ftps://example.something","-e","set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; set ftp:ssl-force true; set ssl:verify-certificate no;cd some_folder;pget "+'"'+fname+'"'])